# C# / Outlook Interop Pickfolder window is not modal

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook

I have a question about an Outlook Pickfolder window.

When I call it directly from the Outlook it works fine and let me choose a folder that I want, acting as a modal window (so it prevents an Outlook window from being clicked on).

But when I call it from my custom WPF Window in the Outlook it behaves as a  non-modal window (not disabling my WPF window and not preventing it from being selected).

So the question is, how do I make it behave as a modal window or how can I disable my WPF window to prevent user input (and even prevent the window from being chosen like when you have a modal window opened)?

I tried to invoke it by a Dispatcher, but it didn't help.

Thanks!

UPD: I use the Outlook API method that calls a Pickfolder window inside.

```
var folder = NetOffice.OutlookApi.Application.Session.PickFolder();
```

And it works fine when I use it directly from Outlook window, but doesn't work from my custom window.

UPD2: For showing my custom window there's something like this:

```
var view = new SettingsPageView();
...
var window = new MyMessageBoxWindow(new MyMessageBoxViewModel());
window.DataContext = view.ViewModel;
window.Content = view;
window.ShowDialog(); // that calls System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog() deeper inside
```

Comment: Can you add related code (the one where you open window)? I'd assume you simply forgot to pass owner window in the `Show()` (or similar) method.

Answer (score 0):

Use IOleWindow and WindowInteropHelper to show your form as a child of the main Outlook window.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
IntPtr wnd = new IntPtr(0);         
object window = _application.ActiveWindow();
if (window != null)
{
    IOleWindow oleWindow = window as IOleWindow;
    if (oleWindow != null)
    {
        oleWindow.GetWindow(out wnd);
    }
}
...

if (wnd != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(archiveSettingWindow);
    window.Owner = wnd;
}
```